# 'Manager' object is unsubscriptable error on Django pagination

Tags: python, django, django-pagination

In Django 1.4.2, I use a simple pagination code like [given in official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/pagination/?from=olddocs#using-paginator-in-a-view):

```
...
paginator = Paginator(songs, 25) # Show 25 songs per page

page = request.GET.get('page')
try:
    songs = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
    songs = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
    songs = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
...
```

When I run that view, I get "***'Manager' object is unsubscriptable***" error on `songs = paginator.page(1)` line. I searched error but I couldn't find any solution about that. What is the problem?

**EDIT:**

`songs` is django model object list. Full view code is like that:

```
def index(request):
    songs = Song.objects

    #filter params
    q_name = request.GET.get('name', None)
    if q_name:
        songs = songs.filter(name__contains=q_name)

    q_composer = request.GET.get('composer', None)
    if q_composer:
        songs = songs.filter(composer__name__contains=q_composer)

    q_composer_id = request.GET.get('composer_id', '')
    if q_composer_id != '':
        songs = songs.filter(composer__id=q_composer_id)

    paginator = Paginator(songs, 25) # Show 25 contacts per page

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        songs = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        songs = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        songs = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'songs': songs})
```

Comment: I think my edit make question more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when there are no filters provided. Then you are trying to paginate a AuditManger and not the queryset. You should change the first query to this:

```
songs = Song.objects.all()
```

Comment: Ohh, I see... I couldn't see that for several hours. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, things happend..All the best!